# Getting different value in array what I push

Tags: angularjs, arrays

I am working on angular project. I am facing error that last value of object shown in all array.

```
$scope.products = [{"product_id":"1", "price:80"},{"product_id":"2", "price:90"}]
```

Now i am using angular forEach method. actually I have much thing I product array so i use a order array where I I provide just id and value

```
angular.forEach($scope.products, function(value, key){
   $scope.order.product_id = value.product_id;
   $scope.order.price = value.price;
   $scope.orderProducts.push($scope.order);

})
```

but I get

```
$scope.orders = [{"product_id":"2", "price:90"},{"product_id":"2", "price:90"}]
```

on my console I saw

```
objet{{"product_id":"1", "price:80"}
```

but when I open then I get

```
 product_id:"2",
 price: "90"
```

Comment: its angular.forEach not .foreach.....how can that executed for you??check this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you doing wrong

```
angular.foreach($scope.products, function(value, key){
   $scope.order.product_id = $scope.products.product_id;
   $scope.order.price = $scope.products.price;
   $scope.orderProducts.push($scope.order);
});
```

Repalce with

```
$scope.orderProducts = []
$scope.products = [{"product_id":"1", "price":80},{"product_id":"2", "price":90}]
angular.forEach($scope.products, function(value, key){
   $scope.orderProducts.push({
        product_id : value.product_id,
        price : value.price
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
angular.foreach($scope.products, function(value, key){
   $scope.order.product_id = $scope.products.product_id;
   $scope.order.price = $scope.products.price;
   $scope.orderProducts.push($scope.order);

})
```

Firstly you should use the value inside the function to get the value of the product at that index .

```
angular.foreach($scope.products, function(value, key){
   $scope.order.product_id = value.product_id;
   $scope.order.price = value.price;
   $scope.orderProducts.push($scope.order);

})
```

Next you are changing the same object in the iteration i.e. $scope.order 
which means the first order pushed in the orderProducts array is changed when you assign the new values in the next iteration . 
You should make a local variable and then push it in the array .

```
angular.foreach($scope.products, function(value, key){
   val orderObj = {};
   orderObj.product_id = value.product_id;
   orderObj.price = value.price;
   $scope.orderProducts.push(orderObj);

})
```

Comment: please dont do simple copy paste.....its angular.forEach not .foreach.....how can that executed for you??check this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach

Comment: @SaEChowdary question was pretty sloppy and unclear the answer here pointed at the actual problems both using the wrong object for getting the values and re-using the same object when pushing into the array, fact that the OP didn't take time to correctly copy and paste their own code shouldn't be a burden on those answering IMO

Answer (score 1):

```
angular.foreach($scope.products, function(value, key){
   $scope.order.product_id = $scope.products.product_id;
   $scope.order.price = $scope.products.price;
   $scope.orderProducts.push($scope.order);

})
```

In the function you are using $scope.products instead of the value and key you are iterating over.  Some other things aren't clear in your question so if you get that corrected and still have a problem maybe review the question to make sure you include enough detail (ideally running sample)

Comment: My Mistake on typing question .. at code I am using value

Comment: Think Swati has the rest of the issue then.